# Time series simulation (Monte Carlo) code

Tags: time-series, stata, montecarlo

I'm trying to make a Monte Carlo Simulation with time series and I can't get what I'm doing wrong due to my little knowledge in Stata.
With my ARMA model I'm able to create a time series with 300 observations.
My idea is to do this process 1000 times and in every process I want to save the mean and variance of the 300 observations in a matrix.

This is my ARMA model:
[image]

This is my code:

```
clear all
set more off

set matsize 1000
matrix simulaciones =J(1000,2,0) *To save every simulation of every time series generated
matrix serie = J(300,3,0) *To save each time series
set obs 300 *For the 300 observations in every time series
gen t = _n
tsset t
g y1=0
forvalue j = 1(1)1000{

* Creating a time series
forvalues i = 1(1)300 {
gen e = rnormal(0,1)
replace y1=0 if t==1
replace y1 = 0.7*L1.y1 + e - 0.6*L1.e if t == 2
replace y1 = 0.7*L1.y1 - 0.1*L2.y1 + e - 0.6*L1.e + 0.08*L2.e if t > 2
matrix serie[`i',3] = y1
drop e y1
}
svmat serie
matrix simulaciones[`j',1] = mean(y1)
matrix simulaciones[`j',2] = var(y1)

}
```

I have no idea how to follow and any idea or recommendation is more than welcomed.

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: what have you tried and what error messages do you get?

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1623932-time-series-simulation-monte-carlo-code  It's always courteous to explain cross-posting